# Remove/Filter object on basis of key-value combination from object

Tags: javascript, filter

How to filter out an object from an large object on basis of certain value of one of the property.

```
defaultSettings = {    
'header1': {
    key: '00_02',
    element: {
        'test1': '',                        
    },
    elementName: 'footer'
},    
'enabled': {},    
'header2': [
    {
        key: '',
        value: {
            msg1: {},
            msg2: 'message2',                
        },
        elementName: 'unwanted-element1'
    }       
],
'header3': {        
    info: '',        
    headline: ''
},        
};
```

I want to remove the object where `elementName: 'unwanted-element1'` from `defaultSettings`

I am trying something like

```
for (let key of Object.keys(defaultSettings)) {                        
    if(key === 'header2'){
        if(key['elementName'] == 'unwanted-element1' ){
            //delete that particular object.
        }
    }
}
console.log(defaultSettings);
```

Output expected :

```
{    
'header1': {
    key: '00_02',
    element: {
        'test1': '',                        
    },
    elementName: 'footer'
},    
'enabled': {},    
'header2': [],
'header3': {        
    info: '',        
    headline: ''
},        
}
```

Kindly suggest better approach to achieve this.

Comment: A `header` can be an object or an array ?

Comment: @dariosicily, its an object

Comment: In your example `header2` key  is referring to an array.

Comment: @dariosicily, its an object, which contains nested array object inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
defaultSettings['header2'] = defaultSettings['header2'].filter(prop => prop.elementName != 'unwanted-element1');
```

So here I am filtering the `header2` by not including the `unwanted-element1` and assigning the result to `defaultSettings` again.